# Network Analyst service area Tobreak value changed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, service-area

[image]

MY problem is that when I was calculating the service area, the Tobreak value had changed.
I selected 500 meter as my default Breaks.

But the result shows me that some "Tobreak" value is smaller than 500

How can I solve this problem?

[image]